# How can I completely remove airflow with pip, conda and miniconda?

Tags: conda, airflow, miniconda

I have airflow installed sometime ago (forgot using pip or conda), I want to remove it completely so that I can start a refresh installation, after pip uninstall and conda remove, I see the following places still have residual airflow:

```
/home/axie/miniconda3/pkgs/airflow-1.10.1-py36_0/bin/airflow
/home/axie/miniconda3/pkgs/airflow-1.10.1-py36_0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow
/home/axie/miniconda3/pkgs/airflow-1.10.1-py36_0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/www/templates/airflow
/home/axie/miniconda3/pkgs/airflow-1.10.1-py36_0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/www_rbac/templates/airflow
/home/axie/miniconda3/pkgs/airflow-1.10.1-py36_0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/bin/airflow
```

Seeing them locate in miniconda3 folder, I tried using miniconda to remove them like below but failed:

```
[axie@hadoop02 ~]$ /home/axie/miniconda3/bin/conda uninstall airflow
Collecting package metadata: done
Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are missing from the target environment:
  - airflow
```

Can I simply delete them?

How to completely remove airflow?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Those are the extracted package files by conda. Doing `conda clean -p` should clean them up.

Comment: Thank you. I manually removed them before I see your answer here. Will try on the other host using miniconda